# moment.js specific format with timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to both parse and format a date with the format given to me by my server guys as

```
yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss.sssZ
2014-05-09,09:00:00.000-0400
```

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), I can parse a provided date via

```
moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD,HH:mm:ss.sssZ")
```

This seems to work okay, however if I were to add `.format("YYYY-MM-DD,HH:mm:ss.sssZ")` I get:

```
2014-04-30,09:00:00.000-04:00
```

For the most part this is okay, but notice the colon in the timezone spot.  It should be `-0400`, *not* `-04:00`.  I can easily strip off the colon, but before I resort to that, is there any other format string I should be using for parsing and formatting the dates?

I've also tried including [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), but this doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/) says use ZZ instead of Z in your format string.